# How to load a dynamic image into a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page and I would like to display a graph.  I want to be able to specify the graph dynamically using DOT language.  So I made a page that takes a DOT expression for the query parameter and returns image content.  Now I can simply add an `img` tag with the appropriate `src.

```
<img src="/dot/png/graph{a--b}">
```

However, some servers have trouble with the long URLs.  Is it possible to get an image via a POST request and display it in the `img` tag with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is having the server return a base64 encoded string of the image data, which you could include in an `img` tag like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,BASE64STRINGGOESHERE">
```

Be warned that the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is not supported in IE7 and below, and that IE8 only allows 32KB of data in a URI.